# Returning fun messages to different injections

Tags: php

I am developing an web application. Where there is an input box to track the orders and its open for anyone. I want to return funny messages if somebody tries to inject vulnerable scripts. For example, if anyone tries the old school trick

```
' OR '1'='1
```

it may return **'Seems you're a beginner! Please study more and try again'**.
Will I have to check the inputs with RegEx ? or there is other nicer way? Anybody developed some scripts like this?

Comment: A regular expression could be used for something like this.  Did you try?

Comment: I didn't start yet, was thinking about it :)

Comment: well, I suppose thinking about it is a start of sorts

Comment: How many are you looking at adding? Why not add a list of possible answers to an array and check if the value exists? Probably not the best way but would be an easy start :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha interesting. Well I could help you to sanitize the input, but if you really want to do so . Try this:

```
public function verifyMessageSubject($ps)
{
    if (!preg_match('%^[A-Za-z0-9"<>/,]{3,100}$%', stripcslashes(trim($ps))))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

If you want to sanitize the input you can try this

```
public function sanitize($data)// CALL THIS FUNCTION BEFORE CALLING ANY OTHER FUNCTION
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = stripcslashes($data);
    return $data;
}
public function isCrudFree($data)
{
    $flags = array("SELECT", "ALTER", "INSERT", "CREATE", "DROP", "TRUNCATE", "DELETE", "=", "GRANT");
    foreach ($flags as $key => $value) 
    {
        $x = stripos($data, $value);
        if ($x !== FALSE)  // find array elements in the given string
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

There are hell lot of ways to sanitize your data. You will have to google a lot to make safe your input, if you have decided to invoke hackers. (Not a good idea)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache ( likely but not guaranteed ) you could perhaps utilise the `.htaccess` to redirect users that attempt malicious commands in urls, POST requests etc

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*(\\r|\\n).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)(<|>|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*(<|>|?|%0A|%0D|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(,|;|:|<|>|?>|?<|/|\\\.\.\\).{0,9999}.* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*({\s?:;};|\/bin\/bash|\/cgi-bin\/|\/dev\/tcp\/|\/dev\/udp\/).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*({\s?:;};|\/bin\/bash|\/cgi-bin\/|\/dev\/tcp\/|\/dev\/udp\/).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(;|<|>|?|?|\)|%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).*(/\*|union|select|insert|cast|set|declare|drop|update|md5|benchmark).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(localhost|loopback|127\.0\.0\.1).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(<|>|%27|%3C|%3E|%00).* [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_decode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} printf.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]

# configure `funny` to intercept the `ref` parameter as an example!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/funny/?ref=$1 [L,R=301]
```